# Block not being called and not animating in IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, objective-c-blocks, cgaffinetransform

I am using **ShakingAlertView** in my app.

https://github.com/lukestringer90/ShakingAlertView

It works perfectly in IOS 6. But after i updating to IOS 7 it didnt animate and the block function for incorrect handing not being called.
Given below is the code for the initialization of shaking alert view.

```
currentPass = [[ShakingAlertView alloc]initWithAlertTitle:@"Enter Current Password" checkForPassword:self.pass
                                                        usingHashingTechnique:HashTechniqueMD5
                                                        onCorrectPassword:^{
                                                            isCurrentPassConfirmed = YES;
                                                            [self._accountSource willScrollToTop];
                                                            self.password.text = @"";
                                                            [self.password becomeFirstResponder];

                                                        } onDismissalWithoutPassword:^{
                                                            //NSLog(@"hi");
                                                            [self showFailedPasswordAlert];

                                                        }];
    currentPass.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
    [currentPass show];
```

Below is the method to animate for shake effect.This is invoked correctly but there is no effect.

```
- (void)animateIncorrectPassword {
    // Clear the password field
    _passwordField.text = nil;

    // Animate the alert to show that the entered string was wrong
    // "Shakes" similar to OS X login screen
    CGAffineTransform moveRight = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 20, 0);
    CGAffineTransform moveLeft = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -20, 0);
    CGAffineTransform resetTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        // Translate left
        self.transform = moveLeft;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

            // Translate right
            self.transform = moveRight;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

                // Translate left
                self.transform = moveLeft;

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

                    // Translate to origin
                    self.transform = resetTransform;
                }];
            }];

        }];
    }];

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: is ShakingAlertView sub class of UIAlertview?

Comment: yes.https://github.com/lukestringer90/ShakingAlertView

Comment: we can not customize UIAlertview in iOS7.

Comment: ok thanks. then can u pls tell why the block not called?

Comment: In your shakingAlertView constructor receives the block property as onCorrectPassword parameter.when you alloc your shakingAlertView atfirst it tries to override UIAlertview method, then only it will assign the block property to shakingAlertView. but before that unfortunately it could't override the UIAlertview because of iOS7 restrictions

Answer (score 2):

iOS7 does not allow you to customize the `UIAlertview`.

1. Better create the custom view subclass of UIView which is draw the
       view programmatically using `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method.
2. And create one more container class(inherited from `NSObject`) which
   is used to create and bind your title/password and OK buttons
       with your custom delegate property into your customized alert
       view.So that we can implement our custom delegate method as like
       `clickedButtonAtIndex` method.
3. Upto my knowledge there is no changes in block/animation in iOS7.

Or refer this link https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 1):

The layout of `UIAlertView` changed drastically is iOS 7, making it almost impossible to customise and alter. You're going to have to come up with a new solution.

Comment: so what solution you are suggesting?

Comment: A standard custom view with a text field. Can't really be that hard to make, can it?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint to confirm that the block really isn't being called? I'm guessing that it is being called but your code inside the block doesn't do anything because you can't manipulate the alert view anymore.

Comment: no i just put an nslog inside the block. but nothing printed.

Comment: Are you sure the `animateIncorrectPassword` method is even being called?

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. There must be some special internal hack going on for `UIAlertView`. The only lesson you need to take from all this is to stop using `UIAlertView` subclasses.